# Resettable fuse failure

Tags: short-circuit, fuses, circuit-protection, polyfuse

I have a 1.1A, 33V resettable fuse in SMD 1812 package. To test it, I connected a 6A 20V source across it. It went up in a flame that lasted a few seconds. Should I conclude that the fuse is out of spec or this is this kind of known issue with resettable fuse of higher amp rating - 1.1A in this case?

A 250 mA, 24V SMD 1206 fuse from the same brand and a 500mA 60V SMD 1802 fuse from another brand held up well under the same test conditions.

Comment: What does the datasheet say?

Comment: "What does the datasheet say?" About what?

Comment: about the soa and general limitations

Comment: soa?? The part number is SMD1812P110TF/33 Here's the datasheet - http://www.pttc.com.tw/DataSheets/Data%20Sheet%20for%20SMD1812%20Halogen%20Free%20-%20P.pdf

Comment: well ... did it reset afterwards?

Comment: It failed as  a short. And couldn't leave it like that as the wires would have melted.

Comment: @Dojo: Did you try multiple ones? might have been one faulty device. Also you didn't tell much about that power source and the test conditions, if its something like a lab bench psu that you set to 6A current limiting, you might get much higher current surges on connect.

Comment: Tried 2 more. Flame and flame with small bursting sound. Power supply is a laptop charger.

Comment: @Dojo: a laptop charger is not a proper device to test this, they are usually not regulated for short circuits and have quite some output capacitance, thus can easily exceed the 20A mark when shorted.

Comment: You have a point